# Passing a parameter to a delegate during creation and maybe use it like std::placeholders

Tags: c#, delegates

I am currently reading up on delegates and I wanted to know if there was a way to create a delegate and pass parameters to that delegate during creation.

suppose I have this method

```
public void test(int a,int b);
```

Now I can do this

```
public delegate void DelegateWithParameter(int a,int b);

DelegateWithParameter d = new DelegateWithParameter(test);
d(1,2); //Works
```

Now how can I create a delegate that has parameters embedded in it so I can simply do this `d();`?

Also can I pass in partial parameters ? Like pass in second parameter during delegate creation and then pass the first parameter during the use ? I know in C++ we use std::placeholders. I wonder if C# has something like that ?

Comment: You can't construct a delegate without a target method, ie. `new DelegateWithParameter()` won't compile, there has to be a method in there. However, let's assume you meant `new DelegateWithParameter(test)`, then you could do this: `Action d = () => test(1, 2);`, and then call `d()` to call `test(1, 2)`.

Comment: Sorry let me fix my code.

Comment: To shorten the list of parameters by 1, you just need another delegate that takes just one parameter. Either declare one, or use `Action<int>`, so you could do `Action<int> d = x => test(x, 2);` and then call `d(42)` to call `test(42, 2);`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, that's not a good duplicate link for this question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere can you tell me how that link compares with std::placeholders::_1 ?? Two different things

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Indeed, I just remembered on a similar question without reading everything here correctly.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a good candidate here though, just have to find it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen can you expand on your answer please. It looks like an interesting approach.

Comment: You can see an example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/53BDfV).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your delegates param-list is that static and you allways provide the same values anyway, why do you even **have** one? So just use this:

```
public delegate void DelegateWithParameter();

DelegateWithParameter d = new DelegateWithParameter(() => test(2, 1));
d(); //Works
```

Comment: its not static unfortunately. Also I would like to know if its possible ? If so how ?

Comment: @MistyD If it´s not static, how should the runtime **ever** know what you mean by `d()`? In the above code you can of course replace `test(2, 1)` by any other call as well, e.g. `test(myInt, anotherInt)`. But be aware on closures here.

Comment: The method is static. But I would like to know if its possible for a delegate to have partial parameters embedded in it

Comment: Something like this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders

Comment: @MistyD I didn´t refer to the keyword `static`. The above approach works for both, `static` and non-static methods.

Comment: I understand that.

Comment: @MistyD What is still unclear then? You see how to pass a method expecting two numbers into a delegate that expects none. Isn´t that your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Basically a delegate is a function signature.

```
public delegate void DelegateWithParameters(int a, int b);
```

Your delegate has a signature of a function that accepts 2 ints as parameters and returns void. In order to call a delegate of that type, you *have* to use two int parameters.

However, you could wrap that delegate in another method, so that you don't have to provide the parameters. Let's say I want to call a delegate above with a default set of parameters. 
Now I could call that function from anywhere, without specifying parameters for the delegate. (Although they will always be necessary)

```
public void CallDelegate(DelegateWithParameters method)
{
    method(1, 2);
}

public void Test(int a,int b)
{
    // Do something
}

// Use it like so
CallDelegate(Test);
```

Or you could have a class with a field containing the delegate for example:

```
class DelegateInvoker
{
    private DelegateWithParameters method;
    public DelegateInvoker(DelegateWithParameters method)
    {
        this.method = method ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(method));
    }

    // Note this signature is parameterless
    public void InvokeDelegate()
    {
        // but you do call the delegate with the required parameters
        this.method(1, 2);
    }
}

// Then call it like this
var delegateInvoker = new DelegateInvoker(Test);
delegateInvoker.InvokeDelegate();
```

A more inline approach would be to create a function on the fly, but it is basically the same thing. You define a new function to wrap the delegate.

```
DelegateWithParameters method = Test;

// define a new, parameterless method to wrap the delegate
var delegateInvoker = () => method(1, 2);
delegateInvoker();
```

Lastly, note that the newly created function actually has another signature. So you could define our new function as a delegate like this:

```
delegate void ParameterlessDelegate();
```

And the last example could become:

```
DelegateWithParameters method = Test;

// define a new, parameterless method to wrap the delegate
ParameterlessDelegate delegateInvoker = () => method(1, 2);
delegateInvoker();
```